# counting Tasks/Users - easier/more efficient way?

Tags: php, arrays

Im working on a simple Task Scheduler,

the code is working, but im not satisfied with it, especially with the count-function.
It counts the Task of every User, so new Tasks can get distributed depending on amount of Tasks.
I wonder if someone has optimizations/tips to make it look/work more efficient.
Im pretty new to PHP so please have mercy :)

Here is my code-snippet

```
  $count = $showRepository->countTasks($class_int);

  $temp = 10000;
  $temp_id = null;

foreach($count AS &$value){
  if ($temp >= $value['amount']) {
      $temp = $value['amount'];
      $temp_id = $value['u_id'];
  }
}

$showRepository->updateTaskmm($temp_id, $task_int);
$latest = $showRepository->latestUser();
foreach($latest AS $lkey => $info){
  echo "<h3>The Task was distributed to: ".$info['name']." !</h3>";
}
```

```
var_dump($count)

array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["u_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["u_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["u_id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["u_id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["u_id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["u_id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

- Taddl

Comment: There's a separate Code Review Stack Exchange where this question might be better received. We tend to fix specific problems with code here, rather than do semi-ambiguous "I don't like my code" type of queries.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry i didnt knew that, i will check it out! Thank youuuuuu ^^

Comment: beware of things that "look more efficient", with functional programming for example, many people have the trend to replace a plain basic loop by a one-liner, but most of the time it's less efficient, because there's a loop anyway under the hood but with the additional overhead of the function call (memory for arguments, etc). If it can be done with a basic loop, it's probably better to keep it like it..

Comment: @Kaddath do you mean, that i might "over-optimize" my Code?

Comment: premature optimization is a thing, yes, usually there's no real reason to micro-optimize code beforehand, it's better to pick the low-hanging fruit when you have an actual performance problem (saves time). But I was rather commenting your sentence "look/work more efficient": work is only what matters for performance, for the look it's better to focus on code readablility than shortening the code length when you work with others (or for the future when you'll work on old codes you have forgotten how they work)

Comment: @Kaddath Thank you :)
thats what i meant with "look" of the code.
I Thought if i start learning optimization from the beginnig its easier, so i wanted some tips, but i see my Code maybe "too simple" to get tips for optimization!

anyway thx for your awnser!

Comment: If you're learning, optimization is a good question to ask of course, ADyson's suggestion is a good one, you usually get pretty good advices on Code Review. I was just warning you against the fact that "looks" can be treacherous; lots of performance optimizations will make the code longer, not the contrary (for example creating a cache system to gain request time), so that one shouldn't always associate short code with better performance